# If X is domain and Y is range, what is Z?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a really small stupid question, but I'm currently self-teaching myself Multivariable Calculus, and I'm just curious if there is a term for this. I did a small google search and didn't find anything, so I would appreciate anything thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean if $Z$ is used as a standard letter to indicate something? I think not. But also $X$ and $Y$ are not standard, they are just common. If you have a composition of functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y \to Z$, you usually use $Z$.

Comment: $Z$ is the letter coming after $X$ and $Y$...

Comment: Lower case $z$ is often used for complex domains, if your question is about that.

Comment: Generally, when talking about functions, when something asks for the domain, you tell where the x-values are defined. Same thing for range with y-values. What would be the equivalent term for z-values?

Comment: In multivariable calculus you might have $x$ and $y$ as independent variables (so the domain consists of pairs $(x,y)$) and the $z$ axis for the codomain. With more context we might be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In single-variable calculus, X is the domain and Y is the range. In 3-D coordinates, X and Y are the domain (i.e., $\mathbb{R}^2$) and then Z is the range.